# How to convert binary data into image file in Python

Tags: python, image, sockets

1. transmit image file into small segment (packet)
   I used python to transmit image file on UDP sockets as required.

   It is required to break the image file into small 'pieces' and in binary format not in string. Size of each packet is 1024B ('content'). And I make the packets.Adding checksum, sequence number,or corrupted data into the packet of 'Sender' is required as well.
2. need to display package of binary data into image
   In the 'Receiver', extract the data from the packet to get 'content'(1024B), is it possible to display the packet data into image? There are transmit in binary format, and I want to show the realtime transmission，eg. data is corrupted, some part of the image(if can be displayed) will be 'blur'.
3. question
   how to display each packet data into an image or cumulative data into images?

Can anyone help? I have searched much but cannot get the solution well.

Comment: show (in question) your code and error message.

Comment: Create a jpeg or other file type with`open`, and write the recieved content line by line